# Writing a CPU/RAM usage log over a period of time to file on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, cpu-usage, logging, top

I'm looking for an application or line of code that would let me observe a process, save the info in a number of variables, then put the gathered info on a file.

I've been trying with variations of `top` but no luck. I am running several CentOS virtual servers, VM is a 2GB RAM, 2 processor.

A script that works over a specified amount of time while writing lines with the info on a text file so at the end I can have a sort of table with the data would work.

I'm going to stress test the server, and I would like to have the data to make some statistics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard `ps` is enough.

```
while true; do ps o pcpu,rsz -p $pid | tail -n1 >>usage.log; sleep $interval; done
```

result:

```
0.0  3352
0.3 31640
0.4 36924
0.5 36052
...
```

First field is CPU usage in %, second is physical memory usage in kbytes.

Comment: thatas perfect, i had already made a long script to clean all the data from a top batch output, but the is way simple better and efficint
i aprreciate t a lot, thanks!

Comment: at the end i kept using my script, since ps gives me the load average which is normally same as CPU% but is not a rule, more info of this in a quick google search

Comment: The %CPU here is not the % used over the interval, but the average percent over the entire running time of the program. I believe this is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about precise timing and want CPU in percentage:

```
watch --precise -n 1 'top -b -n 1 -p [PID] | tail -n 1 | awk "{print \$9}" >> [PID].log'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [`sadc`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sadc) / [`sar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar).

Comment: Isn't it system-wide only?

Comment: @whitequark: It depends on the version of `sar`. Some versions use `sar -x PID` others use `pidstat -p PID`.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to observe how much cpu time a particular process is requiring.

I was going to suggest [CPU stat tool for CentOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/600893/cpu-stat-tool-for-centos/600913#600913)   but this gets it for the whole system, not just one process.

Any one process will show CPU time in the output of ps:

```
$ ps -ef | egrep blah
root     13988 11152  0 Dec16 ?        00:00:05 sshd: xxx [priv]
xxx      14024 13988  0 Dec16 ?        00:06:00 sshd: xxx@pts/0
xxx      14032 14024  0 Dec16 pts/0    07:00:00 -bash
root      1194   679  0 Apr24 ?        2-05:15:14 [kswapd0]
root      1195   679  0 Apr24 ?        2-06:35:49 [kswapd1]
```

- 00:00:00 is hours/minutes/seconds of cpu.  It will accumulate.
- You'll need permissions to see this if the user is not you.
- Once this value gets above a day the format changes; above it's 2 days.  Your parsing routine will have to handle this.

At this point, parse the output with Python, work some date math on it, and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

The following command gets the average of CPU and memory usage every 40 seconds for a specific process(pid)

```
pidstat 40 -ru -p <pid>
```

Output for my case(first two lines for CPU usage, second two lines for memory):

```
02:15:07 PM       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
02:15:47 PM     24563    0.65    0.07    0.00    0.73     3  java

02:15:07 PM       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
02:15:47 PM     24563      6.95      0.00 13047972 2123268   6.52  java
```