# Log CPU usage to file for specific process over time

Tags: cpu-usage, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am looking to log CPU usage to a file over time on an RHEL system, and have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/149961/cpu-ram-usage-log-over-a-period-of-time-to-file-on-centos), but it doesn't seem to produce the right results - it seems like an anomaly between how `ps` and `top` calculate CPU usage.

I am trying to profile an Openfire server's CPU usage as we run various load tests against it. The script I am using does this:

```
while true;
do
dateStamp=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000000))
echo -n $dateStamp >>usage.log
ps -o pcpu,rsz -p $1 | tail -n1 >>usage.log; sleep $2;
done
```

But the first data item from `ps` (`pcpu`) seems to be cumulative - I would like a simple number for current CPU usage, as is provided by `top`.

Does anyone know of an approach that provides this?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [nmon](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/) (with nmon analyser). You can get much more than just CPU usage and its extremely easy to use.

Comment: Looks fantastic, but sadly I won't be allowed to install it on the machine I am doing these tests on :(

Comment: This is for a Java app - I ended up using the values exposed through JMX to get the information I wanted (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information/61727#61727 for more information). I'm going to accept this answer anyway as it would have done the trick had I had more freedom on the machine!